# C exec multi commands

Tags: c, exec

i am struggling and your input would be really appreciated. i'm trying to chain arguments to the command line using exec and an array to hold the arguments. the problem comes when I try to chain more than one command. tried using an ";" to separate each command but that does not seem to be working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>enter code here

int main(){

    int proc1 = fork();
    char*myargv[16];
    myargv[0]="/bin/ls";
    myargv[1]="-F;";
    myargv[2]="pwd";
    myargv[3]=NULL;

    if(proc1==0){
            execve(myargv[0],myargv,NULL);
            exit(1);
    }else{
            wait(NULL);
            printf("This wlways last");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `execve` can only execute one command. It can't be used for chaining. If you want to run more than one command then you need to use multiple `fork/execve` calls or exec  a script that runs all the commands or if your shell supports it can run the shell with those commands.

Comment: If you want to execute two commands, you have to call `exec` twice, once for each command. Of course, as you know, executing a command needs a lot more than calling `exec`, and you have to do all of that for each command. I think the point of this assignment is, at least in part, to get you to understand that. You might want to review the [documentation for `exec`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html). Reviewing how the shell interprets a command line might also be handy; you probably have some assigned readings.

Comment: The 'real' shell (standard shell) doesn't pass the `;` to the command — it splits the command line at the semicolon and splits what's before it into one command which is executed, and then splits what's after it into another command which is executed.

Comment: You should probably capture the PID and status that's returned by `wait()` so that you can report on what you got.  You should end `printf()` messages with a newline for more reliable printing.

Comment: the posted code fails to check for when a call to `fork()` fails ( the returned value is -1 ).  A call to any of the exec family of functions never returns unless some error occurred.  so after the call to `execve()` should be: `perror( "execve failed" )` followed by the call to `exit()`

Comment: suggest:  after the call to `wait()` to insert the code for the next command